# How to specify, that the accepted generic type has to be of a specific type from among several

Tags: typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
type ValidTypes = TOptBoxParams | TOptInputParams | TOptInputParams | TOptColorParams | TOptSelectParams;

type TOtherType<T> = {
}
```

I need that the  "T" type only accepts one of type "ValidTypes", how can I do it?

Comment: You have to use the extends keyword like `type TOtherType<T extends ValidTypes>={}`

Comment: I have already tried that, but VSCODE still accepts if you put another type, I want it to put it in red if I don't put one of the valid types.

Comment: Could you provide an example ?